# SQL two Fk in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

Let's imagine the situation below.

I'm a company that sells services to private schools and independent students.

Sometimes student pay to himself as beneficiary:      **STUD -> STUD**

Sometimes school pay to himself as beneficiary:       **SCHO -> SCHO**

other case School can pay for Student as beneficiary: **SCHO -> STUD**

in the end, I need to create an Invoice for the Payer including the beneficiary name.

I have independent tables for the student and schools.

**tbl_Student** (**id_Student, Student_name**)
**tbl_School** (**id_School, School_name**)

I need to fill out **tbl_Invoices (id_invoice, id_payer, id_beneficiary**, price,...)

So, the point is that **id_payer** and **id_beneficiary** can receive FKs from **id_student** and **id_school**)

My initial idea is to add two more columns on the **tbl_Invoice** and create a new table as below:

First a tale to identify if its a school or student:
**tbl_ClientType (id_ClienteType**,...)
1 = School
2 = Student

now I add on the **tbl_invoice (FK_Id_PayerType, FK_Id_BeneficiaryType)**, being:
**id_invoice, id_payer,FK_Id_PayerType, id_beneficiary, FK_Id_BeneficiaryType**, price,...

So, I fill the table with **id_payer**, **id_beneficiary** columns with their respective Student or school ID.
and identify columns **FK_Id_PayerType**, **FK_Id_BeneficiaryType** with their **id_ClienteType** 1 or 2, so I know id the **id_payer** and **id_beneficiary** is from the School or Student table.

My point is to use the same column for two different "fks" doesn't look to be the correct way to do it. But I can't have another idea.

Comment: Create routing table with `party_id, party_type_id` columns and reference it with FK. Or use different columns for different types. Or move all this logic to the application. It depends on the flexibility you need.

Comment: Using the same column for multiple foreign keys is perfectly legal -- what I call "forking foreign keys"; there's no technical problem about that. However, the real question is if it does correctly model your problem.